# Agrandar caja al 100% usando display:flex

Tags: css, css3, flexbox

Estoy utilizando la propiedad `display:flex` pero al tener esta estructura:

```
<div class="cajaFlexible">
<div class="cajaHija"></div>
<div class="cajaHija"></div>
</div>
```

Y con este css:

```
.cajaFlexible{display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
.cajaHija{flex:0 1 auto;}
.cajaHija{flex:0 1 auto;}
```

No consigo que las cajas hijas me ocupen el 100% del ancho del div y no se por qué, he probado varios valores (flex 0 1 100%, y algunos más que no recuerdo) y no me ocupan nunca el 100% del div.

¿Qué propiedad/valor me está faltando?

Código de Ejemplo:

```
<footer class="pie">
  <section class="contenedor">
    <article class="pie-flex">
      <div class="pie-izquierda">
        <figure class="logo-inferior">
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/imagenes/logo-gris.png"/>
        </figure>
        <div class="contacto">
          <p>Aqui van datos de contacto</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pie-derecha">
        <nav class="menu-inferior">
          <p>dato de menu</p>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</footer>
```

CSS para dicha estructura:

```
.pie-flex {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 250px;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
    -o-justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    -o-align-items: center;
    color: #9d9d9d;
}

    .pie-izquierda {
        flex: 0 1 75%;
        -webkit-flex: 0 1 75%;
        -moz-flex: 0 1 75%;
        -ms-flex: 0 1 75%;
        -o-flex: 0 1 75%;
    text-align: left;
        display: flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: -o-flex;
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        -moz-align-items: center;
        -ms-align-items: center;
        -o-align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
        -moz-justify-content: flex-start;
        -ms-justify-content: flex-start;
        -o-justify-content: flex-start;
    }
    .pie-derecha{
        flex: 0 1 25%;
        -webkit-flex: 0 1 25%;
        -moz-flex: 0 1 25%;
        -ms-flex: 0 1 25%;
        -o-flex: 0 1 25%;
    }
```

Comment: No veo problema con tu código, funciona perfectamente como tú quieres: https://jsfiddle.net/L8k3ref3/3/

Comment: En el nuevo ejemplo que pones tienes un div al 25% y otro al 75% y ya no los tienes en columnas. Funciona según lo esperado también: https://jsfiddle.net/vfhjawnj/1/

Comment: Si, y al ponerlos en la regla del @media los pongo al 100% y nada, se queda al tamaño que tenían inicialmente y no abarcan todo el contenedor. Es lo que no entiendo..he probado con `flex:0 1 100%`y con  `width:100%` y nada.

Comment: Deberías poner un ejemplo que reproduzca el problema y no ejemplos que funcionan correctamente. Si te he entendido bien con media queries pones los `div` en columnas, cambia la alineación de center a strecht:  `align-items: stretch`.

Answer (score 2):

El problema que estás teniendo es que necesitas agregarle un tamaño al div contenedor, ya que si no sus elementos hijos no saben cuanto deben de ocupar.

Ejemplo:

```css
.cajaFlexible{
  display:flex;
  width: 500px; 
  height: 500px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.cajaHija1{flex: 1 1 auto; background-color: red;}
.cajaHija2{flex: 1 1 auto; background-color: blue}
```

```html
<div class="cajaFlexible">
  <div class="cajaHija1"></div>
  <div class="cajaHija2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: el div padre (.cajaFlexible) lo tengo también al `width:100%` y se me queda ahí al mismo tamaño, al tamaño de lo que le ocupa el contenido en vez de a lo que mide el contenedor padre

Comment: entonces debes definir un valor en elemento que está por encima del div padre, que este caso supongo que es el body. si no, no sabe el 100% de que tamaño tomar

Comment: @Marcos Si quieres usar porcentajes siempre debes de usar unas proporciones en su elemento padre para que pueda tomar como referencia estas proporciones. Si no, no tendrá en cuenta ninguna proporción ya que no sabrá que tamaño coger.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero están los bloques con su 100% (edito más arriba). Lo tiene tanto `cajaFlexible` como el contenedor que lo engloba a ellos (con un `width:100%,max-width:1200px;`. De ahí que me extrañe que los cajaHija no me ocupen el 100% de la pantalla cuando redimensiono, no se qué estoy haciendo mal

Comment: @Marcos ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo que sea reproducible? Así puedo ver el comportamiento que te está realizando actualmente y puedo partir de ahí para solucionarlo.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero puesto en la pregunta inicial, para que se pueda ver mejor ;)

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que dices en los comentarios entiendo que tienes algo así (dos `div` en vertical que tienen el ancho de su contenido en lugar del 100%):

```css
.pie-flex {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  color: #9d9d9d;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pie-izquierda {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.pie-derecha {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<footer class="pie">
  <section class="contenedor">
    <article class="pie-flex">
      <div class="pie-izquierda">
        <figure class="logo-inferior">
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/imagenes/logo-gris.png" />
        </figure>
        <div class="contacto">
          <p>Aqui van datos de contacto</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pie-derecha">
        <nav class="menu-inferior">
          <p>dato de menu</p>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</footer>
```

Para solucionarlo deberías eliminar  `align-items: center` de `.pie-flex` o mejor aún sobreescribirlo porque es posible que si estás modificando los elementos con *media queries* lo heredes. Cambia el valor a `strecht` para que se estire ocupando todo el ancho disponible:

```css
.pie-flex {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: strecht;
  color: #9d9d9d;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.pie-izquierda {
  flex: 0 1 75%;
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.pie-derecha {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<footer class="pie">
  <section class="contenedor">
    <article class="pie-flex">
      <div class="pie-izquierda">
        <figure class="logo-inferior">
          <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/imagenes/logo-gris.png" />
        </figure>
        <div class="contacto">
          <p>Aqui van datos de contacto</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pie-derecha">
        <nav class="menu-inferior">
          <p>dato de menu</p>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</footer>
```